# Changing subform sourceobject

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In access 2010 database, I  have a master form **FormMaster** and a subform  **SubFrm** and I also have option group with two options optionA,option B on main form

what I want to achieve is when user changes the option ,I want to bind **frmOpA** to subform and when user checks option B I eant to bind **frmOpB** to subform FormSub

I was able to get this working using the after update event of the option group using the following code

```
Private Sub FrameTgt_AfterUpdate()
Select Case FrameTgt.Value
Case 1
Forms("FormMaster").Form.SubFrm.SourceObject = "frmOpA"

Case 2
Forms("FormMaster").Form.SubFrm.SourceObject = "frmOpB"
End Select

End Sub
```

the code changes the subforms source object fine but it doesn't seem to pull the data i.e it doesn't requery

I have tried

```
 Case 1
    Forms("FormMaster").Form.SubFrm.SourceObject = "frmOpA"
    Me!Subfrm.Form.Requery
```

but it doesn't seem to refresh 
I have also tried to link master and child fields in vba but no use !

any ideas?

Comment: What is your FilterOnEmptyMaster setting? What are your LinkMasterFields and LinkChildFields? Are they the same for both subforms?

Comment: FilterOnEmptyMaster: Yes and Yes they have same master and child fields!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you throught about creating two FormMaster one with frmOpA and the other with frmOpB? 
You could then use a the on click event of the option group to move between the forms.

Answer (score 2):

Your SourceObject string should be prefixed by "Form." to distinquish it from other object types like "Table.", "Query.", or "Report."

Try:

```
Forms("FormMaster").Form.SubFrm.SourceObject = "Form.frmOpA"
```

and

```
Forms("FormMaster").Form.SubFrm.SourceObject = "Form.frmOpB"
```

instead.  Hope this helps.